# How to send email to a user upon receiving an email from another user?

Tags: php, laravel, email, notifications, laravel-5.7

So I am trying to build a system that works like the **facebook email notifications** where a `user` receives an **email** based on some actions performed by another `user`.

Then, the **first** `user` may reply to that **email** and the **second** `user` will also get their reply.

Now I understand how to send basic emails. But the thing about this is that there is no direct communication between the 2 `users`.

Every email is sent through me and I then relay the mail to the appropriate recipient.

I am trying to do this using Laravel 5.7.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @WebArtisan okay, I found some articles on google talking about "piping an incoming email".

Comment: Yes, “piping an incoming email” (to your script, so that it can analyse & act upon it) is basically what you’ll want to do … so, go deepen your research on that; unless you have a _specific_ question …?

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what you want to do, but basically you can use events and listeners to send email to specific user after some action , so if your email contains a link that redirect users to some point in the application you can trigger the event when the user enter the redirecting point.

here is Laravel doc about events

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/events